# What is the best practice for having html tags change their style after changing URL in Django?

Tags: django, frontend

[image]

Suppose I have this kind of navbar, the buttons in which turn white when you click it (adding an "active" class). But if the button redirects to a new url, the navbar renders anew, and the home icon is highlighted as it is by default. How to drag that "active" class on a button after a redirect? What is the best practice in that regard? Do I ask the wrong question?

Comment: And what is this "remaining/static styles" idea is called? So that I could read about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

**views.py**

```py
def render_about(request):

    # include title in context
    context = {
        'title' : 'About'
    }

    return render(request, 'about.html', context=context)
```

Then in your navbar:

**base.html**

```
<nav>
  <a class="{% if title=='Home' %}active{% endif %}"> Home </a>
  <a class="{% if title=='About' %}active{% endif %}"> About </a>
  ...
</nav>
```

And then add the styling for the `active` class in your css file.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that does it. Is it the only thing to know about this pattern?

Comment: Nope - I usually implement this navbar in all of my django projects.